# Angular click event is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass an angular variable into a function click call.
this is what im trying to do so far:

```
<button onclick="dialogBox(id)">Cancel</button>     

    $scope.dialogBox = function (id) {
     console.log('Succesfully submitted id: '+id);
    });
```

Comment: ng-click="expression"

Comment: @Dylan is spot on about `ng-click` instead of `onclick`. Make sure that the `dialogBox` function is available to the scope that the button is on (typically inside a controller or directive). Also, what's the `id` variable? with the given code, id isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` is a normal JavaScript event binder instead of an Angular one. You need to use global variables/functions in the `onclick` expression. However, in your code, `dialogBox()` is a function of `$scope`. So, if your `button` tag is wrapped inside the corresponding controller, just use `ng-click` instead. Like:

```
<button ng-click="dialogBox(id)">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: As a reminder, if you found this answer useful (and you should, since it is the correct answer), you should select it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ng-click is the to slove this problem

```
<button ng-click="dialogBox(id)">Cancel</button>
```